# Different Color for region of intersection

Tags: vertices, geometry

Is there a simple way to make a region or new object in order to change the material properties at the intersection of two or more objects?
For example:
[image: 2d]

[Or this, where the intersection area of interest is shown in orange and is the intersection between 3 different objects](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/DTS/Sum05/WebPages/Faith/sphere-cone-intersection.gif)

I have read a little about using the Boolean tool for Union, Intersection, and Difference between two objects, but when applied, it does not create a new region or object. It destroys part of the objects that are present and replaces it with the union, or whichever is chosen.
In addition, if the intersection is chosen, the resulting object is not the type of intersection shown below. The intersection given would be the plane with the bottom part of the cone sticking down for some reason.
Is there a better way to achieve the question above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Boolean Modifier" doesn´t work as expected with non-manifold meshes. When you add a plane use the "Solidify Modifier" first, to give it a slight thickness (e.g. 0.0001).

Give the plane a "Boolean Modifier" afterwards and set the target to the cone. Set "Operation" to "Difference". Copy the plane with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to avoid moving the copy. For the copy set the "Operation" of the "Boolean Modifier" to "Intersect".

Edit: The pictures show the Modifier Tab in the Properties Panel (click the wrench icon). **Note that the order of the modifiers in the modifier stack is important.**

[image]

[image]

You could also parent the two planes so they can be moved around together. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select both plane objects with <kbd>RMB</kbd>. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and select "Object".

Afterwards materials can be assigned on every object separatly.
You can then use Freestyle for line rendering.

The advantage of using modifiers is fast editing and your objects are easy to animate.

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much!  I noticed you mentioned that the area of intersection will update if the planes are under a parent.  I tried this but it didn't work quite like your gif. I ended up getting this: http://imgur.com/a2DHHqP . I'll keep trying on it.  Also, was the gif you prodivded made from the same blender model? Every time I try to get a translucent material, the objects behind it lose their coloring for some reason.

Comment: Yes this is raw blender output. The image you linked doesn´t show your setup. Can you provide the blend file or show some settings and the object hierarchy in the "Outliner"? Btw. I used blender 2.70 and loaded the default file before setting the scene up though it shouldn´t make much of a difference. Did you try to rebuild the scene or something else?

Comment: Also in the image you provided I see many horizontal lines that indicate extreme Z-fighting. Is thickness set to 0 or are there any overlapping copies?

Comment: I noticed that when i keep the thickness at the default ~0.01, it works OK, but when I tried changing it to ~0.00001 it gave the problem. Does that sound right or make sense?

Comment: It should work with both values actually.

Comment: To see what is going on I would need see the whole setup. There are many reasons why it could fail. Did you just add a cone and a plane or did you something fancy like scaling non-uniform in object mode etc?

Comment: This is the Blender file I am working with at the moment:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxdHiPHlGyRlTVVtSEphb09NWU0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here some things i noticed: You applied the modifiers. That will practically freeze everything into your mesh (usually unwanted). The plane has still 0 thickness or the modifier was removed. The hierachy of the parenting went wrong. You need 2 planes in one place and parent one to another.

Comment: I made a quick screencast (no audio) [link to video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04Cd2NwajRTZTJUQmc/edit?usp=sharing). This should roughly explain what I meant.

Comment: Awesome, I think I got it! That video is fantastic for beginners!